# Access multiple DBs using one connection and one query via codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have a question regarding mysql db and codeigniter framework

I want to use one query accessing multiple DBs using **codeigniter** which returns one resultset
Example as follow:

```
SELECT A.name, B.class_name
FROM DB1.Table1 AS A, DB2.Table1 AS B
WHERE A.id = B.id
```

Return one result????

Following are my connection setting in codeigniter

```
$db['DB2']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['DB2']['username'] = 'connection_name';
$db['DB2']['password'] = 'connection_password';
$db['DB2']['database'] = 'DB2';
$db['DB2']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['DB2']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['DB2']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['DB2']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['DB2']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['DB2']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['DB2']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['DB2']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['DB2']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['DB2']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['DB2']['stricton'] = FALSE;


$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'connection_name';
$db['default']['password'] = 'connection_password';
$db['default']['database'] = 'DB1';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Kindly provide me some sample code which helps to run the above query.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not possible to help you without your data. Posting username and password to access your database at `localhost` doesn't help. ;)

Comment: Hello memowe,
May be I am not clear to you.

I need to know what is the procedure. So why do you need data for that?

Actually my question is very simple i.e. how to use a query which access two DBs using **codeigniter framework**

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I didn't understand you correctly. I thought your question "Return one result????" was about why you get only one result. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

Create 1 connection to the DB1 with a MySQL user for that database, for example user `x` and give user `x` privileges to `DB2` in MySQL too, this way you can use one connection and access more than 1 database in queries ...

Comment: Sorry if I didn't clearly specify my problem due to my poor English :(

Actually I am facing problem when I use codeigniter.

I have given user x privileges to DB1 and DB2 both. And I am able to access it using NAVICAT DB tool.

But I don't no what is the procedure for **codeigniter framework**

Comment: Do a test before getting to codeigniter part, use phpMyAdmin to connect to your database using user `x` (DO NOT CONNECT AS root OR OTHER USERS) and test your query there to make sure it works, if it's working then you should look for problem in codeigniter, else your user definition has a problem.

Comment: Thanks Night2 for your valuable comment,
I checked it with new user testuser and its working fine on mysql console. and NAVICAT tool.

But the problem is in codeigniter because 
we use $this->db
instead I need $this->db_group type of thing
which can access multible DBs in a group.

So do you have any clue?

Comment: Could you update your Question with the code of using connection and sending your query? By seeing that, I may be able to help.

Comment: Hello Night2,  
If you talk about code then It should be look like as follow  
$sql = "SELECT A.name, B.class_name  
FROM DB1.Table1 AS A, DB2.Table1 AS B  
WHERE A.id = B.id"  
$query = $this->db->query($sql);  
    
Problem is $this-db->query only exicute 1 database query  
I need to access two DBs as show in query  
    
I hope this clear my problem

Comment: Can't you use something like this: `$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('TABLE');
$this->db->join('DB2.TABLE', 'DB2.TABLE.FIELD = DB.TABLE.FIELD');`

Comment: Hi NIght2,
Good try but its not working either.
    
I tried this one
$this->db->select('*'); 
$this->db->from('TABLE'); 
$this->db->join('DB2.TABLE', 'DB2.TABLE.FIELD = DB.TABLE.FIELD');
    
Even I tried this one
$this->db->select('*'); 
$this->db->from('TABLE'); 
$this->db2->join('DB2.TABLE', 'DB2.TABLE.FIELD = DB.TABLE.FIELD');

and all other possible combinations.

Actually when you run it $query = $this->db->get();
means you call **db** so there is a limitation of using **1 DB** only. :(

I hope in future version codeigniter do some thing for that to access multiple DBs with one query.

Comment: I'm not sure, but if it's not working then their Database class is lacking something, you can still use built in MySQL functions or better than that, MySQLi ...

Comment: You are right But now what I am doing a little bit trick
making view of DB1 table in DB2
and then access it using DB2
Its working for now but I know that is not a solution
Thank you very much for your time and help
Best regards